# Angular Typeahead result in target div

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

Is it possible to put the angular ui typeahead results in a separate div on the page instead of the default. I have seen this SO post [AngularJS typeahead search results in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326273/angularjs-typeahead-search-results-in-a-div) but wondering if anybody have already tried this.

Answer (score 3):

Search for `$document.find('body').append($popup);` in the [typeahead.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js).

If the `typeahead-append-to-body` attribute that is by default set to `False` changes to `True`, the result will be append to the `<body>`

`<input type="text" typeahead-append-to-body="true">`

If you change the `$document.find('body').append($popup);` to something like `$document.find('#myElement').append($popup);` , the result will be append to the element with id `#myElement`.

You can define your attribute , something like `typeahead-append-to-myElement`